# Overwrite VS Code snippet with user defined snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured the following TypeScript snippet in Visual Studio Code

```
"console.log": {
        "prefix": "cl",
        "body": [
            "console.log();"
        ],
        "description": "console.log()"
    }
```

It doesn't work however, because there is already a snippet defined for the `cl` (class). How can I overwrite that snippet with mine? I'd like to use `cl`, because I have other IDEs configured the same way and would prefer not change my convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `cl` a list of all the possible expansions of the cl snippet is shown and your snippet is probably around the bottom of the list. In order to access the snippet at the top of the list you can added the following to your `settings.json`

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "typescript.useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.tabCompletion": true
}
```

Here notice the `editor.snippetSuggestions`. This is the setting which defines the sorting of the autocomplete list which appears when you type your snippet's abbreviation. By default it is `bottom` which is why your snippet appears at the end of the list.